# Convergence or Divergence of infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series

> $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {z^n\over(n + 1)!}$

So I got $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {z^n\over(n + 1)!} - 1$.
I understand that if $|z|<1$ then $z^n$ approaches 0 as n approaches infinity. This leaves me with $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {0\over∞} - 1$. I appreciate everyone's input. And sorry for the formatting.

Comment: Perhaps you could spell out what equations or statements you are working from.  As it is, it is very difficult to understand what your notation means.

Comment: Essentially the infinity sign goes to the top of ∑ and the n=1 or n=0 go the bottom. The terms in the brackets is the sequence. I hope this helps. If anyone know how to format a series function in MathJax that would be appreciated.

Comment: I have formatted the first statement.  Can you follow that example and finish formatting the rest?

Comment: @abiessu thanks. yeah ofcourse.

Comment: @user277658 Do you know many z such that |z|<0?

Comment: @user277658 Sorry thats a typo. Its supposed to be |z|<1. |z|<0 is impossible.

Answer (score 2):

Note that
if
$a_n 
=\frac1{(n+1)!}
$,
then
$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}
=\frac{\frac1{(n+2)!}}{\frac1{(n+1)!}}
=\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+2)!}
=\frac1{n+2}
$.

Therefore
$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}
\to 0
$
as
$n \to \infty
$.

What does this tell you
about the
redius of convergence?

Comment: this tells me 1/(n+1)! converges to zero. $z^n$ converges to zero when |z|<0. thus the infinite series converges to zero.

Comment: Look up the ratio test. The *terms* converge to zero; the *sum* most definitely does not.